# Ссылка на внутренний ресурс

Tags: modx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать такое.
Имеется дерево ресурсов:

```
ресурс
    вложенный ресурс
```

в чанке генериться ссылка таким макаром

```
[[~[[+id]]]]
```

эта ссылка на собственный ресурс, как сделать что бы ссылка вела на вложенный  ресурс ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ура решение найдено.

1) Создаем сниппет с таким содержимым

```
$depth = isset($depth) ? $options : '1'; // default limit to 1 levels deep
$array_ids = $modx->getChildIds($input,$depth,array('context' => $modx->context->key));
if(!is_array($array_ids)) return $input; // if no children, we will return the id     resource
return $array_ids[0];
```

2)Вызываем его в шаблоне таким методом

```
[[~[[+id:getChildIdResoirceId]]]]
```

3) По умолчанию глубина стоит 1, если вам нужно её изменить, просто передайте в опции, т.е. к примеру на 3

```
 [[~[[+id:getChildIdResoirceId=`3`]]]]
```

Вот и все решение. Большое спасиибо форуму MODx, а именно **Artdevue**

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, что вы вставляете чанк в ресурс и ссылка получается на сам ресурс, а надо на дочерний? Попробуйте воспользоваться вот [этим сниппетом](https://gist.github.com/bertoost/3074939).

Comment: Извеняюсь может не правельно выразился, сниппет работает, дело в том что мне нужно все в точности на оборот, что бы ссылка вела с корневого ресурса на вложенный в него ресурс.